# Возврат дробной части

Tags: c

Нужно написать функцию, что возвращает дробную часть.

Типо: из 45.5 должно показать 0.5

Answer (score 6):

Стандартная функция, которая разрезает плавающее значение на целую и дробную часть, называется `modf` (`modff`, `modfl`)

```
double w, f = modf(45.5, &w);
/* `w` - целая часть, `f` - дробная часть */
```

или (если вас не интересует целая часть)

```
double f = modf(45.5, &(double) { 0 });
/* `f` - дробная часть */
```

Имейте в виду, что обе полученные таким способом части будут иметь такой же знак, как и исходное значение.

Comment: Забивать новичку голову временными объектами (`&(double) { 0 }`) ни к чему?

Comment: к тому же в Си таких штук нет...

Comment: @Fat-Zer: Есть, разумеется. Это - обыкновенный чисто С-шный *compound literal*, а не "временный объект". Не путайте.

Comment: @avp: А что этом мире не временно? :) Однако можно заметить, что этот объект является существенно менее "временным", чем временные объекты. Не вижу причин, почему бы новичку не познакомиться с этим свойством языка.

Comment: @AnT, просто меня удивило, что в ответе для новичка вы словами не рассказали, что это за штука.

Answer (score 1):

Всё, догадался :D

```
 float Function(float a) {
 int b;

 b = a;
 return a-b;
 }
```

Comment: А результат этой функции для отрицательного числа вас устроит?

Comment: Зачем создавать функцию, если уже есть готовая? Преподаватель потребовал не использовать готовые функции, да?

Comment: Да, есть такое.